# “ca.der: No such file or directory” when run alexa-avs-sample-app-master

Tags: ios, objective-c, alexa-skills-kit

When I run `alexa-avs-sample-app-master`, this error occurs:

> ca.der: No such file or directory

Then I remove `ca.der` from project, it can run up but crashes in:

```
NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ca" ofType:@"der"];"
```

Help.

Comment: you have to create your own ca.der

Comment: how to create ca.der ?